# $_POST is empty when using Jquery Ajax calls also header already send warning appears

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing a PHP project and I need to send data from HTML page using jQuery Ajax to another PHP page.

But the `$_POST` is showing empty when I try `echo`. I tried to debug this issue, did millions of searches on Google with no success. 
Another thing is the `IDE` shows *warning* somewhat similar to this `Cannot modify header it's already sent`

---

**index.html**

```
 <html>
   <head>
   <title>Dashboard</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <form id="labelForm" name="labelForm" method="post">
             <label for="label">
              Create Label
                  <input id="label" name="label" type="text">
             </label>
             <input id="create" id="create" type="submit" value="Create">
       </form>
       <script type="text/javascript">
             $('#labelForm').submit(function (event) {
             event.preventDefault();
             alert("Send");
             $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'storerole.php',
                  data: {
                       pos:"aky"                
                  },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

---

**storerole.php**

```
<?php
   var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

---

**Additional Information**: I also used AJAX Debugger for Chrome and found the AJAX request in the Console which indicates that AJAX did it's job and the issue is in PHP.
PS: Stackoverflow searching is also done a lot.

**EDIT 1**
Output `array(1) { ["pos"]=> string(3) "aky" }` is shown in the Console of Chrome using AJAX Debugger while output `array(0) { }` is shown in the `storerole.php`

**EDIT 2**
Removed `action` from `form` to avoid confusion.

Comment: Use `{pos:"aky" },` to send parameter using ajax

Comment: @Saty Sorry I made a typo mistake in the question. I have already used " : "

Comment: Update your original code!!

Comment: So what exactly do you see in the console when you click submit?

Comment: @Steve I see this `array(1) {
  ["pos"]=>
  string(3) "aky"
}`

Comment: Then its working!! POST is not empty at all - what is your problem?

Comment: @Steve
It should but when I print `$_POST` or use `$_POST["pos"]` or `$_POST['aky']` in php it shows NULL.
Then how should I access the `$_POST` data

Comment: I dont understand - your php has `var_dump($_POST);` and it displays the contents of `$_POST` as expected. If you changed it to `echo $_POST["pos"];` you should see `aky` in the console - does that not work?

Comment: @Steve That's the confusion. The output of `var_dump($_POST)` is `array(0) { }`

Comment: You just said (4 comments above) that the output is `array(1) { ["pos"]=> string(3) "aky" }` now you say its `array(0) { }`??

Comment: Ok, i think i have guessed what you are doing - see my answer and comment if you have any more questions

Comment: @Steve I added it more in the question

Comment: Yes, thats exactly as i guessed - did you read my answer? php wont remember the post data from a previous request when you make a new one (loading the php file in a browser is a completely new request, the previous post data from the ajax request has been deleted from memory by this point) - why do you need to use ajax if you are then opening the file in browser? Why not just do a regular form submit as suggested?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99823/discussion-between-akshay-chordiya-and-steve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is stateless - if you make an ajax post request, that is one request, containign post data. You will see the response from that request in the javascript `data` variable (visible in your browsers js console if you do `console.log(data);`)

If you then visit `storerole.php` in the browser, that is a second, seperate GET request, (with no POST data).

If you want to visit the page in a browser, just do a normal form submit, eg remove the javascript and let the browser submit the form:

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Dashboard</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
        <form id="labelForm" name="labelForm" action="storerole.php" method="post">
             <label for="label">
              Create Label
                  <input id="label" name="label" type="text">
             </label>
             <input id="create" id="create" type="submit" value="Create">
       </form>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

***which indicates that AJAX did it's job and the issue is in PHP***

So, you should debug at the serverside then, as you have posted the markup and js.

---

*IDE shows warning somewhat similar to this Cannot modify header it's already sent*

There is no issue developing using any IDE but you should test your application in the updated browsers like chrome, firefox etc.

You should have an eye on browser's console to see the js errors. This definitely produces an error.

You can't use `=` sign in the js object:

```
pos="aky"
```

change to this:

```
pos : "aky"
```

---

Comment: Sorry I made a typo mistake in the question. I have already used ":"

Answer (score 0):

Data in ajax is sent in javascript array notation syntax so data would be in format :

```
data: {'param1' : 'data' , 'param2' : 'data' }
```

Comment: specify the method for your ajax .. its like `method:'POST' ` ... it should be like `$.ajax({
            url: "",
            method: 'POST',
            data: {thread_id :  last_msg_id  },
            }).done(function( data ) {
              
        });`

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax content you used = in your data. you should use : instead

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'storerole.php',
              data: {
                   pos : "aky   //use : here                
              },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data values as given below :

```
data: { 
        'value1':'val1','value2':'val2','value3':'val3'               
      }
```

And for the error "Cannot modify header it's already sent" you can use ob_start() at the top of php file.